# Finding keywords in a string/paragraph

Tags: python, keyword-search

I have a function called similar that identifies if the two words are similar.

I need to find if any keyword exists in the Paragraph. These keywords can be 3 words,2 words or 1 word. For example: clutch,power steering, Intelligence control unit or control unit.

How do I implement it? I have only figured out to find the keywords for 1 word keyword only. I am splitting the paragraph at the the spaces. Removing stopwords using nltk and using itertools.product to compare the two lists. Can someone help me?

Comment: SO is not an advice forum or a code writing service. Please update your question with what you've tried so far. Show your code so we can help you fix it.

Comment: The dupe should answer your question. I've used RAKE and it is a powerful tool. Next time, please look up these things yourself. We are here to solve programming problems, not offer advice on software tools. Cheers.